# Validate "Owin OAuth Bearer Token" from NodeJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, node.js, api, oauth

I am creating an App in Angular that connects to two APIs.
The first API was developed in C# .NET and, among other things, is the responsible for handle the authentication based in Owin OAuth2.
When the user log-in the API gives a token.

I am creating the second API in NodeJS...and i want to use the token from C# API to access the NodeJS API.

The tokens aren't stored in DB, so i need to "validate" this in the NodeJS API.

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can get token from C# API by using `http.request` and then validate it.

```
var options = {
    path: '<API path that gives token>',
    method: 'GET'
};

http.request(options, function (res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}).end();
```

Comment: The question is how to validate the token. I already have the token. Thanks!